# 'ChebConv_Coma' object has no attribute 'weight'

Tags: python

my code

```
import torch
from torch_scatter import scatter_add
from torch_geometric.nn.conv import MessagePassing
from torch_geometric.nn.conv.cheb_conv import ChebConv
from torch_geometric.utils import remove_self_loops

from utils import normal

    class ChebConv_Coma(ChebConv):
      def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, K, normalization=None, bias=True):
        super(ChebConv_Coma, self).__init__(in_channels, out_channels, K, normalization, bias)

      def reset_parameters(self):
         normal(self.weight, 0, 0.1)
         normal(self.bias, 0, 0.1)
```

I get the message:

```
File "/home/jack/pytorch_coma/layers.py", line 14, in reset_parameters
    normal(self.weight, 0, 0.1)
  File "/home/jack/.conda/envs/COMA/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 948, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'ChebConv_Coma' object has no attribute 'weight'
```

I don't know what to do next.Is there anything wrong with the ChebConv?

Comment: are you sure you are using torch_geometric 1.3.2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved the problem?

I've checked the **Cheb_conv.py** and have a guess: the Parent Class `message_passing` has no attribute called weight, and instead since it's an implementation of a Graph Network(the discrete model), the corresponding `self.weight` should be `self.lins[k].weight` (the linear transform matrix), so to replace `self.weight` with `self.lins[k].weight` may help with the issue.

Here is the reference link about GNN(message passing) with pytorch:
https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/create_gnn.html#creating-message-passing-networks

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def reset_parameters(self):
    for lin in self.lins:
        normal(lin.weight, 0, 0.1)
        normal(lin.bias, 0, 0.1)
```